# Need to record video with a DSLR using an SDK

Tags: c#, camera, edsdk

I want to be able to control a DSLR camera to start/stop recording video.
Canon has a nice SDK, but it seems that Video capture is not supported.
Anyone know if Nikon SDK supports this ?
Maybe there is a workaround for shooting video using Canon's SDK ?

Thanks.

Comment: solution has beed found in linked question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037929/how-to-start-stop-video-recording-on-canon-camera-via-sdk/11169517#11169517

Comment: I decompiled the EOS utility (it is a .Net app) to find the secret to doing this. However ,EDSDK version 2.11 now has documented support for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is impossible using Canon's SDK. I solved this with a hack - using a USB-IR transmitter that sends the signal used by a Canon Remote to start/stop video. Ugly but works.

Comment: It has to be possible, since the EOS Utility that comes on the CD with the camera supports it.

Comment: It is possible, just not with the documented Canon SDK. There must be some undocumented trick to do it, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Another hack: you might be able to capture the liveview images and stitch them together into a movie file.

Comment: I thought of that, but there are too problems. The FPS is not very hig, and of course there is no sound.